# Asymptotic Equipartition Property and $1-\epsilon$ lower bound

Tags: information-theory

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typical_set) and [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eaarti/Class/10704/lec6_srccoding.pdf) and [here](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee376a/files/lecture_notes.pdf), the lower bound on the probability that an element is $\epsilon$-typical is $1-\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$, and this is derived by using the asymptotic equipartition property which states that the limit of this probability as $n$ goes to infinity is $1$. But why $1-\epsilon$? Can't we pick any number less than n as a lower bound? Why not $1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which is higher?

Am I misunderstanding how the AEP is applied? Or is there a practical reason why this lower bound is chosen instead of a better one?

For clarification, the standard result given in all the resources linked above is:

For sufficiently large $n$:

$$\Pr(x^{n}\in A_\epsilon^{(n)})\geq 1-\epsilon$$

But for sufficiently large $n$, every lower bound is true. Why choose the $\epsilon$ in $1-\epsilon$ to be the same as the $\epsilon$ in $A_\epsilon^{(n)}$? I am yet to see a compelling reason for choosing this than a better bound.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pick different values for the $\epsilon$ in $1-\epsilon$ and the subscript in $A_\epsilon^n$ -- let's call them $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$.  If you make $\epsilon_1$ smaller, though, you'll typically need to make $n$ larger for it to be "sufficiently large".  As long as you aren't looking for explicit bounds on how large $n$ needs to be, none of this matters: if you have a result using $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, I can just take $\epsilon=\min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$ and get the same result.

Formally, the "sufficiently large" condition is saying that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a finite $N(\epsilon)$ such that the result holds for $n>N(\epsilon)$.  You can also write it as saying for every $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2>0$ there is a finite $N^*(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$ such that the inequality holds for $n>N^*(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$.  If you take $\epsilon=\min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$ these are equivalent.

When it **does** matter is when you want to be explicit about what $N(\epsilon)$ looks like -- eg, if you want an explicit bound in terms of $\epsilon$.  In that case you may get a better bound by treating $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ separately. It might turn out that the best bound in some setting comes from having $\epsilon_1\ll \epsilon_2$ rather than having them equal.

Comment: I understand the definitions. I'm trying to understand the motivation for every source  giving a bound like this. Why would it be useful? For an arbitrary $n$, it doesn't let you guarantee anything. And if you are allowed to pick $n$ sufficiently large, then you can make the bound as high as you like.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition $1.$** *Let $(X, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}, \mu) $ be a measure space. Let $\langle f_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of extended real-valued $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}$-measurable functions on a set $D\in\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}.$ $\langle f_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in measure $\mu$ on $D$ if there exists a real-valued $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}$-measurable function $f$ on $D$ such that for every $\varepsilon >0$ and $\eta> 0,$ there exists $N_{\varepsilon,~\eta}\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\mu\{D:|f_n-f|\geq \varepsilon\}<\eta\tag1\label 1$$ for $n\geq N_{\varepsilon,~\eta}.$*

**Observation $1.$** *$f_n\overset{\mu}{\to}f$ on $D$ if and only if for every $\delta > 0,$ there exists $N_\delta\in\mathbb N$ such that $$\mu\{D:|f_n-f|\geq \delta\}<\delta\tag2\label 2$$ for $n\geq N_\delta.$*

How is $A^{(n) }_\varepsilon$ defined?

**Definition $2.$** *The typical set $A^{(n) }_\varepsilon$ with respect to $p(x)$ is the set of sequences $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathcal X^n$ with the property $$2^{-n(H(X)+\varepsilon)}\leq p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\leq 2^{-n(H(X)-\varepsilon)}.\tag 3\label 3$$*

So, $A^{(n) }_\varepsilon$ is defined specifically for $\varepsilon.$

From the very definition,

$$ (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in A^{(n) }_\varepsilon\implies H(X) -\varepsilon \leq -\frac{1}{n}\log p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\leq H(X) +\varepsilon.\tag 4\label 4$$

By AEP,

$$-\frac{1}{n}\log p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\overset{\mathbb P}{\to} H(X). \tag 5\label 5$$

Therefore, in the spirit of $\eqref{1}, \eqref{2}$ and using $\eqref{4}, \eqref{5}, $

\begin{align}\mathbb P\left\{A^{(n) }_\varepsilon\right\}&= \mathbb P\left\{\left|-\frac{1}{n}\log p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)-H(X)\right|<\varepsilon\right\}\\ &> 1-\delta \\\implies\mathbb P\left\{A^{(n) }_\varepsilon\right\} &> 1-\varepsilon~~\textrm{using}~\eqref{2},~~\forall~n\geq n_0\in\mathbb N. \tag 6\label 6\end{align}

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration, *J. Yeh,* World Scientific, $2014, $ section $\S 6,$ pp. $111-112.$

$\rm [II]$ Elements of Information Theory, *Thomas M. Cover, Joy A. Thomas,* John Wiley & Sons, $2006, $ section $3.1, $ p. $58.$

Comment: I understood the proof already, I think. I am questioning why it is useful to have such an arbitrary bound, when any bound works.

Comment: The conspicuous thing is that $A^{(n) }_\varepsilon$ depends on $\varepsilon$ and that's why the subscript. See how the proof went. It used the definition that is based on $\varepsilon$ which holds for "sufficiently large" $n.$ You want $\varepsilon/2? $ Take $A^{(n) }_{\varepsilon/2}$ and there exists $n_0$ such that $\forall n\geq n_0,~ \mathbb P\left\{A^{(n) }_{\varepsilon/2}\right\} > 1-\varepsilon/2.$

Comment: On another note, as is evident from $(1)$ one can choose $\eta$ anything: for $\eta:=\varepsilon/2,~\mathbb P\left\{\left|-\frac{1}{n}\log p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)-H(X)\right|<\varepsilon\right\}\\ > 1-\varepsilon/2 ,~\forall~n\geq N_{\varepsilon,\varepsilon/2}\in\mathbb N. $ But does it matter? It is not about any special choice of $\varepsilon, $ rather it is about the specific nature of the typical set, its characterization which is done with $\varepsilon.~ |A^{(n) }_{\varepsilon}|\leq 2^{n(H(X)+\varepsilon)}$ and $ |A^{(n) }_{\varepsilon}|\geq(1-\varepsilon)2^{n(H(X)-\varepsilon)}$ ...

Comment: for sufficiently large $n.$ The choice of $\varepsilon$ is immaterial. The main thing is typical set's cardinality and the high probability of its occurrence.